# Can I convert the visible light into another form of electromagetic light form?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, frequency

can I convert the visible light form into another form of electromagnetic light? actually I want to make a device which convert the objects which are visible to the human eye into invisible as a part of my project work.can I?

Comment: A car parked in the sun does that quite effectively, converts visible and near ultraviolet into infrared.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Shine light on a surface and it will heat up the surface. The surface will now emit radiation.

You also have processes like fluorescence and phosphorescence where a molecule absorbs light and radiates it (usually) in a lower frequency.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and is a highly researched topic. The professional terms are -

- [up-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion) -converting light to higher frequencies, such as green to blue (visible) or X-ray (invisible) etc.
- down-conversion-converting light to lower frequencies, such as green to red (visible) or infra-red (invisible) etc.

Examples to fields that use this extensively are [high harmonic generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_harmonic_generation) for up-conversion and photovoltaics (~solar cells) for down conversion.

However it is much more abundant process. Nice example of down-conversion is the standard fluorescence light sources. The current inside the lamp produces high-frequency (invisible) light, which is down-converted to visible light at the fluorescent material at the edge of the lamp.

Basic terms for starting to optimize these processes are -

- energy levels/spectrum of the converting materials (gives the possible conversions of the material)
- absorption efficiency of it to the chosen incoming light (for example it can be negligibly absorbing one frequency and highly absorbing another. Thus much smaller input power of light with the second frequency will emit much more light at the end than a lot of input power of light with the first frequency)
- branching ratio/spectrum of the output (usually you wish to emit a certain frequency, however materials can emit at a broad range of frequencies. You wish to optimize the spectrum around your chosen frequencies, and don't want 90% of its emission spectrum to be useless for you).

There exist other conversion schemes however most of them are much less efficient, to my best knowledge.